# Who lives on the Shadow Plane?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e, planes, e6

## Important Note

While I do understand that the DM is ostensibly God in his game. My GM does generally respect most things written in book.

## Explanation

I have a character who is connected with the Shadow Plane in a E6 D&D3.5 Pathfinder Hybrid game, and I was talking to my DM who said that nothing lives in the shadow plane. However, I am sure that that I've read about some creatures that are native to the Shadow Plane. In addition, I think there's a template to turn creatures into Shadow creatures.

## Question

What published examples can I show him within our scope that prove the Shadow Plane has significantly inhabited regions?

I'd appreciate answers including page numbers for any referenced materials.

## Scope

D&D 3.5 (No 3rd Party) + Pathfinder + [E6](http://dungeons.wikia.com/wiki/E6_%283.5e_Sourcebook%29)

I would like to know of anything that is **outside** the scope of **E6** however please **note it as such** because it will need extra **special DM approval** to use, as well as a good explanation as to why I should be allowed to use it.

Comment: @Dakeyras: Thank you for the edit it made it much more readable and fixed a fuw typos.

Comment: The more I think about it, on some level, this question doesn't really fit on this site, I think. It's basically asking for a list of Shadow Plane denizens, which is [explicitly not on topic](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/181/4563). You need to figure out if there is a specific answer that you're looking for.

Comment: @KRyan agreed. The second question appears on topic but the first does not, according to the meta referenced.

Comment: Yeah, sorry man but we try not to allow questions that are "list every single X where X is a big ass list." If you can refactor this into a question with a more definable best answer we can reopen it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no one "Shadow Plane"/"Plane of Shadow"/"Shadowfell" because it is only an archetype that different games use. There is no one canonical "shadow plane". It is the GM's discretion as to what to veto and what to include. Might seem harsh, but a GM has got to do what a GM has got to do. If it works for your game, good.

The civilization most players are familiar with is the [Shadar-kai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadar-kai). They first appeared in *Fiend Folio*, for D&D 3.0, and later the *Monster Manual* for 4th Edition. There are also a race of language worshiping humans called [Illumians](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ex/20041203a&page=2) which were detailed in *Races of Destiny*. Forgotten Realms also has a race of humans called [Shade](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Shade) who live in the Shadow Plane and who are much like the Shadar-Kai.

MAny campaign setting's Shadow Plane have an ecology;

From the [Forgotten Realms Wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Plane_of_Shadow)

> The best-known inhabitant of the Plane of Shadow is the shadow. Others are generally evil and dangerous, including the dusk beast, the ecalypse, the nightshade, the shadow mastiff and the umbral banyan.

From a [Greyhawk Wiki](http://www.canonfire.com/wiki/index.php?title=Plane_of_Shadow#Inhabitants)

> Inhabitants of the Plane of Shadow include the khayal genies, dark ones, darkweavers, shadar-kai, shadelings, gloamings, shades, shadows, slow shadows, shadowswyfts, greeloxes, cloakers, illumians, nightshades, shadow dragons, and shadow demons.

The [Plane of Shadow from Eberron](http://eberron.wikia.com/wiki/The_Shadow_Plane) contains life too.

Comment: [Forgotten Realms Wiki](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Shadar-kai) may also be useful to look at for Shadar-Kai

Answer (score 4):

Lots of things live in the Shadow Plane.

For example, the Dark template from *Tome of Magic* can be applied to any creature; it’s kind of the Shadow Plane equivalent to the Celestial and Fiendish templates. Unlike those templates, however, Dark is quite excellent: among other things, it gives Hide in Plain Sight, as an LA +1 template. (do note that RAW, not all forms of HiPS are the same, and Dark’s version only eliminates the need for concealment/cover, not the need to avoid direct observation – this makes it more like the Ranger’s Camouflage than the Ranger’s version of Hide in Plain Sight. Many DMs treat all forms of HiPS as covering both requirements of Hide, though)

There are similar templates for Shadow Plane versions of creatures, but those aren’t as good (much more LA).

In general, *Tome of Magic* has a lot of information on things from the Shadow Plane, because an entire third of the book is devoted to Shadow Magic. Note: I do not recommend the Shadowcaster; it is a rather underwhelming class.